# SUM all values in a column, where cells in a second column match the cells in a third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the SUMIF function to sum an amount where the codes in two other columns match eachother. However I am unsure how to build this formula and I haven't succeeded yet, I am getting confused that on sheet 1 there is one row and on sheet 2 multiple rows have to be checked.

Sheet 1:

```
Code         Amount
XXXXX-1481   8
XXXXX-1913   5
XXXXX-2013   8
XXXXX-8329   10

XXXXX-1481   11

XXXXX-1913   6
```

Sheet 2:

```
Code         Total amount
XXXXX-1481   
XXXXX-1913
XXXXX-2013
XXXXX-8329
```

I want to SUM all values in column 'Amount' on sheet 1 in column 'Total amount' on sheet 2, where the codes from sheet 1 and 2 match. The codes will occur multiple times in the table in sheet 1, but only once on sheet 2. The result should be a filled 'Total amount' column:

```
Code          Total amount
XXXXX-1481    19    
XXXXX-1913    11
XXXXX-2013    8
XXXXX-8329    10
```

I am curious how others would solve this. Thank you in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: Supposing (`Sheet1` as first sheet, `Sheet2` as second sheet and `Code` as Cell A1)

`=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$9;"="&Sheet2!A1;Sheet1!$B$1:$B$9)` on Cell B2 at Sheet 2

If you have more than 8 items, then make it bigger.

Hope it helps

Comment: It worked after some finetuning! Thank you very much and the good part is I understand the formula now :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume your "Source" data put in Sheet1 `A1:B10` with header and blank rows

In "Result" sheet 2, `A1:B1` put header "Code" and "Total amount"

Then,

In `A2`, formula copied down :

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100),0),0))&""
```

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A2="","",SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B))
```